# what are the possible reasons that HttpResponseHeaders .contains() throws exceptions in C# with HttpClient?

Tags: c#, .net, httpclient, response-headers

The question is about the use of 'HttpClient' in C#. When i do with response from  a server end, I meet the below problem.
I use ' hc.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation(name, headMap[name])'

```
            HttpClient hc = new HttpClient();
            hc.Timeout = new TimeSpan(1000000000);
            HttpContent content = new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8);

            if (headMap != null && headMap.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (string name in headMap.Keys)
                {
                    hc.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation(name, headMap[name]);
                }
            }

            HttpResponseMessage responseM = hc.PostAsync(new Uri(url), content).Result;
            endTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss zz", new CultureInfo("en-US"));

            HttpResponseHeaders headers = responseM.Headers;
            IEnumerable<string> values;
            if (headers.Contains("Content-Length"))
            {
               ...
            }
```

When I test the codes to ‘headers.Contains("Content-Length")’， it throws a
System.Exception: Misused header name. Make sure request headers are used with HttpRequestMessage, response headers with HttpResponseMessage, and content headers with HttpContent objects.

I think the exception info is lack of use.

Can you tell me the possible reasons to the exception throwed out of 'headers.Contains("Content-Length")'?

Answer (score 0):

you can check for a header presence like this

```
if(Request.Headers["Content-Length"] != null)
```